# How to get unix timestamp for today 11 AM and tomorrow 11 AM in local time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have figured out that probably I have to use `date` function to get today and tomorrow and than use `strtotime` to convert it into unix timestamp. I just cannot understand how can I remove the time part from `date` and replace it with 11AM and pass it to `strtotime`. I have already added `date_default_timezone_set` to set to local timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` takes all kinds of crazy formats, you can just do this:

```
$stamp1 = strtotime('today 11 am');
$stamp2 = strtotime('tomorrow 11 am');
```

Comment: And you are not even kidding. Bravo !

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an object orientated approach I'd recommend PHP's `DateTime` object.

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$today->setTime(11, 0, 0); //hour, minutes, seconds

$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$tomorrow->setTime(11, 0, 0);

$todayTimestamp    = $today->getTimestamp();
$tomorrowTimestamp = $tomorrow->getTimestamp();
```